# Answered question with positive scored answer appearing in unanswered question list

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

Someone flagged [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1380/100) today and notice it is in the unanswered question list. However, it is answered with an answer score of +3.

I'm creating this post for two reasons:

1. I opened up a thread on meta.SE to discuss this bug as this may affect also other sites aswell: [Answered question with positive scored answer appearing in unanswered question list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284580/226837)
2. I want you to know that flagging such a question is the *wrong* place to do it. I really appreciate the hint, but in future please just create a thread on meta, it's so much easier and more transparent to communicate here.

Thanks and stay tuned.

Comment: Strange bug. Will be interesting to follow on meta SE.

Comment: I was the one flagging it, sorry didn't know that was the wrong course of action. will go to meta first next time :)